# I'm getting an error: _CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart, android-emulator

When I create a new user the error (_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)) appears at User.fromSnap ...as Map<stringm,dynamic> and firebase creates the user auth but not the user data

How can I add array of array of objects to Firebase?

```
    class User {
      final String email;
      final String uid;
      final String photoUrl;
      final String username;
      final String bio;
      final List followers;
      final List following;
    
      const User(
          {required this.username,
          required this.uid,
          required this.photoUrl,
          required this.email,
          required this.bio,
          required this.followers,
          required this.following});
    
      static User fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
        var snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
       *_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)*
    
        return User(
          username: snapshot["username"],
          uid: snapshot["uid"],
          email: snapshot["email"],
          photoUrl: snapshot["photoUrl"],
          bio: snapshot["bio"],
          followers: snapshot["followers"],
          following: snapshot["following"],
        );
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "username": username,
            "uid": uid,
            "email": email,
            "photoUrl": photoUrl,
            "bio": bio,
            "followers": followers,
            "following": following,
          };
    }
```

**auth_methods.dart**

```
class AuthMethods {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // get user details
  Future<model.User> getUserDetails() async {
    User currentUser = _auth.currentUser!;

    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).get();

    return model.User.fromSnap(documentSnapshot);
  }

  // Signing Up User

  Future<String> signUpUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String username,
    required String bio,
    required Uint8List file,
  }) async {
    String res = "Some error Occurred";
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty ||
          password.isNotEmpty ||
          username.isNotEmpty ||
          bio.isNotEmpty ||
          file != null) {
        // registering user in auth with email and password
        UserCredential cred = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );

        String photoUrl =
            await StorageMethods().uploadImageToStorage('profilePics', file, false);

        model.User _user = model.User(
          username: username,
          uid: cred.user!.uid,
          photoUrl: photoUrl,
          email: email,
          bio: bio,
          followers: [],
          following: [],
        );

        // adding user in our database
        await _firestore
            .collection("users")
            .doc(cred.user!.uid)
            .set(_user.toJson());

        res = "success";
      } else {
        res = "Please enter all the fields";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return err.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }

  // logging in user
  Future<String> loginUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    String res = "Some error Occurred";
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty || password.isNotEmpty) {
        // logging in user with email and password
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
        res = "success";
      } else {
        res = "Please enter all the fields";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return err.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
  }
}

    
    //this is my user.dart file
    //this is an instagram clone
    //I am getting error in login page
```

Comment: This error tell you that snap.data() is null and thus you can't cast null to a Map<String, Dynamic>.

Can you provide User.data() source code?

Comment: sorry, how do i do it.

Comment: Sorry i misread your code.
is this error an error from IDE or an execution error?
In case of execution error, this tell that you pass null instead of a Map to fromSnao call. 
Can you provide the source code wher fromSnap is called?

Comment: no problem, this is an execution error. I edited the code.

Comment: Have you check if this line `DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).get();` return a null value?
 If it return null you have deal with this.

Comment: thank you, it was solved by sending the value to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

`snap.data()` returns `null`. If that is not intended behavior then you should investigate. Also you can cast to `nullable` type:

```
final snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?; //snapshot is now nullable
```